# web indexer using Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing, web-crawler, distributed-computing

Is parallel system or distributed system better for web site crawlers and web indexers when developed in Java?  What are the available frameworks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the best crawler/indexer combos you'll ever find for Java is [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/), which is an Apache project now (see [Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Features)) and thus open source.

**Features:**

1. Fetching, parsing and indexation in parallel and/ou distributed
2. Plugins: plain text, HTML, XML, ZIP, OpenDocument (OpenOffice.org), Microsoft Office (Word, Excel, Powerpoint), PDF, JavaScript, RSS, RTF, MP3 (ID3 tags)
3. Ontology
4. Clustering
5. MapReduce
6. Distributed filesystem (via Hadoop)
7. Link-graph database
8. NTLM authentication (Windows/Exchange/etc)

Answer (score 1):

Nutch is unbeatable. Another more simple lib which I used successfully in projects is https://crawler.dev.java.net/. You find examples on https://crawler.dev.java.net/samples.html.